# Is there ever an instance where you need to get the first number in this reduce function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The question seems like a trick question—only because one of the requirements I get back when I submit the function for validation is the following.

> should_return_the_smallest_element_in_an_array_when_there_are_ties

Why should/would we be checking for ties in numbers??

```
1 === 1 //returns true.
```

Am I missing something?

This is the actual requirements.

> Write a function called "findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements".
>
> Given an array of mixed elements,
>   "findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements" returns the smallest number
>   within the given array.
>
> Notes:
>   * If the given array is empty, it should return 0.
>   * If the array contains no numbers, it should return 0.

```
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr) {
  var containsNoNums = function(arr){
   return arr.every(function(cv){
      return Object.prototype.toString.call(cv) !== '[object Number]';
    });
  };

  if (containsNoNums(arr) || (!(arr.length))) return 0;

    var smallestNumber = arr.reduce(function(shortest, e){
        return (( e <= shortest) ? e : shortest);
    });

    return smallestNumber;

}

var output = findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements([4, 'lincoln', 9, 'octopus']);
console.log(output); // --> 4
```

Comment: Your method returns string if there is a string passed inside the array, ie for [ 5, "4" ] the results would be "4", not 5 nor 4.

Comment: Is there any way you can find out what input the validator is using?

Comment: @KarlReid Sorry could you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your solution is that a string that contains a single number is considered a number.

Consider the array

```
[4, 'lincoln', 9, '3']
```

Your solution will return '3' which is an error, it should return 4.

Sometimes an external iteration can be easier to understand with a problem like this. There is no need to be using a functional approach for a search like this especially when it can be done with a single pass over the array.

```
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr) {
    var smallest = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var n = arr[i];
        if (typeof n == 'number') {
            if (smallest === null) {
                smallest = n;
            } else if (n < smallest) {
                smallest = n;
            }
        } 
    }
    if (smallest === null) {
        smallest = 0; 
        // This handles the case of not finding a number 
        // or if the array was empty. 
    }
    return smallest;  
}

console.log(findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements([4, 'lincoln', 9, '3']));
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible `Array.reduce` based solution might look similar to the following one ...

```js
var rejectSmallestNumberValue = (function (baseValueOf) {
  function valueOf(type) {
    return ((type == null) ? type : baseValueOf.call(type).valueOf());
  }
  function isNumberValue(type) {
    return (typeof type == 'number');
  }
  return function reject (collector, item, idx, list) {
    var
      value = valueOf(item);

    if (idx === 0) {

      collector.value = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }
    if (isNumberValue(value)) {
      collector.isContainsAnyNumber = true;

      collector.value = Math.min(collector.value, value);
    }
    if ((idx >= (list.length - 1)) && !collector.isContainsAnyNumber) {

      collector.value = 0;
    }
    return collector;
  };
}(Object.prototype.valueOf));


console.log("[4, 'lincoln', 9, 'octopus', '0.5'].reduce(rejectSmallestNumberValue ...) : ", [4, 'lincoln', 9, 'octopus', '0.5'].reduce(rejectSmallestNumberValue, {

  isContainsAnyNumber: false,
  value: 0

}).value);

console.log("[4, 'lincoln', 9, 'octopus', '0.5', 1].reduce(rejectSmallestNumberValue ...) : ", [4, 'lincoln', 9, 'octopus', '0.5', 1].reduce(rejectSmallestNumberValue, {

  isContainsAnyNumber: false,
  value: 0

}).value);

console.log("[14, 'lincoln', 9, 'octopus', '0.5'].reduce(rejectSmallestNumberValue ...) : ", [14, 'lincoln', 9, 'octopus', '0.5'].reduce(rejectSmallestNumberValue, {

  isContainsAnyNumber: false,
  value: 0

}).value);

console.log("[14, 'lincoln', 'octopus', '0.5'].reduce(rejectSmallestNumberValue ...) : ", [14, 'lincoln', 'octopus', '0.5'].reduce(rejectSmallestNumberValue, {

  isContainsAnyNumber: false,
  value: 0

}).value);

console.log("['lincoln', 'octopus', '0.5'].reduce(rejectSmallestNumberValue ...) : ", ['lincoln', 'octopus', '0.5'].reduce(rejectSmallestNumberValue, {

  isContainsAnyNumber: false,
  value: 0

}).value);

console.log("[].reduce(rejectSmallestNumberValue ...) : ", [].reduce(rejectSmallestNumberValue, {

  isContainsAnyNumber: false,
  value: 0

}).value);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```